# Choosing destination when installing a chocolatey packages with Puppet

Tags: nuget, puppet, chocolatey

I have created a chocolatey package that is going to get deployed with Puppet to my test server. The package is basically just a bunch of static resources (CSS/JS) zipped together:

```
Install-ChocolateyZipPackage 'WebResources' '\\teamcity\WebResources.zip' "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
```

What would be the best way, using chocolatey, to extract these files to my website folder? It's just at the moment putting everything in the default `c:/chocolatey/lib folder`.

I've been thinking of 2 ways:

1. Include a script file that copies the files.
2. changing the chocolatey env variable to point to my site.

None of them feels right. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the package to install the files to your wherever the script file is running from. This `"$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"` is the destination. If you want to have that change, you should probably put an environment variable on the machine you are targeting and then have it use that if available and default back to this...

Comment: We decided to solve this issue with an environment variable containing the path. We also had to modify the installation ps script (inside the package) to read this variable and pass it to the 'Install-ChocolateyZipPackage' command of course.